# Backbone getting model for a clicked element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Say I have a collection of sportsmen. I juste display their names and when there's a click on a name, I'd like to dislay some more details. But that implies I have to retrieve the associate model.

So I have a model, a collection and then two views, one that takes care of rendering each individual name, and the other one manages the list of those names. And then I'll have to create a view to display the details of the clicked sportsman.

But I can't figure out how to retrive the associate model. If I place my event in the view that manages the list, it triggers on click but there's an error saying that the model is undefined.

And if the event listener is located in the view that renders each individual name, it doesn't do anything on click.

Here's my code :

**Index.html**

```
<script id="nameListTemplate" type="text/template">
    <%= first %> <%= last %>
</script>
<script id="contactTemplate" type="text/template">
    <ul>
    <li><%= first %></li>
    <li><%= last %></li>
    <li><%= age %></li>
    <li><%= sport %></li>
    <li><%= category %></li>
    </ul>
</script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script src="js/models/sportsManModel.js"></script>
<script src="js/collections/sportsMenCollection.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/nameView.js"></script>
<script src="js/views/nameListView.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<ul id="sportsMenName"></ul>

<div id="sportsManDetails"></div>
```

**sportsManModel.js**

```
var app = app || {};

app.SportsManModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

**sportsMenCollection.js**

```
var app = app || {};

app.SportsMenCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.SportsManModel
});
```

**nameView.js**

```
var app = app || {};

app.NameView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'sportsMan',
    template: _.template($('#nameListTemplate').html()),

    /*events: {
        'click .sportsMan': 'showSportsManDetails'
    },
    // here it doesn't work at all
    showSportsManDetails: function(e){
        alert(this.model.get('first'));  
    },*/

    render: function(){
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.attributes));

        return this;
    }
});
```

**nameListView.js**

```
var app = app || {};

app.NameListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#sportsMenName',

    initialize: function(sportsMen){
        this.collection = new app.SportsMenCollection(sportsMen);
        this.render();
    },

    /*events: {
        'click .sportsMan': 'showSportsManDetails'
    },
    // here it says that this.model is undefined
    showSportsManDetails: function(e){
        alert(this.model.get('first'));  
    },*/

    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(sportsMen){
            this.renderContact(sportsMen);
        }, this)
    },

    renderContact: function(sportsMen){
        var nameView = new app.NameView({
            model: sportsMen   
        });
        this.$el.append(nameView.render().el);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is the exact error, you see in console?

Comment: TypeError: this.model is undefined if I listen to the event in NameListView. If I listen in NameView, just nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you have a view for `li.sportsMen` element so you don't need to use class `.sportsMen` in events at all.

And second problem you had wrong method name for click event `showSportsManDetails` but should be `showContactDetail` as you have `showContactDetail` method or rename method name to `showSportsManDetails` instead.

```
app.NameView = Backbone.View.extend({
...
    events: {
        'click': 'showSportsManDetails'
    },

    showSportsManDetails: function(e){
        alert(this.model.get('first'));  
    },
```

Here is a working example http://jsbin.com/yutaduvokehu/1/edit

Comment: I edited my post to correct the method name that didn't match as it's a transcription problem and not part of my initial mistake. Thanks again

Comment: Yes that works! The two methods that don't correspond are due to the fact that I changed my code to have a simpler exemple for SO. But where I was wrong, in fact, is with the 'click .sportsMan' instead of just 'click'. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem may be with the scope , try adding this initalize function in nameView :

```
initailize : function(){
   _.bindAll(this,'showContactDetail');
}
```

Comment: That does nothing. No error but no function triggering neither. I had found this post, which uses _.bindAll too, but I can't make it work in my case… http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/10/11/backbone-js-getting-the-model-for-a-clicked-element/